# Failed load PDF from file DJANGO using embed tag

Tags: django, pdf, embed

Im trying to load a PDF

My .html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <embed src="{{ documento.adjunto.url }}" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="600px" />
        </div>>
    </div>
</div>
```

Where documento.adjunto its the url where the document its saved (in my case  "curriculums/CV_2017.pdf")

It throws me Failed to load resourse: 404 not found http://127.0.0.1:8000/INTRANET/uploads/curriculums/CV_2017.pdf

But there is where the PDF is saved

Model:

```
UPLOAD_CVS = "curriculums/"
class Curriculum(models.Model):
    rut_candidato = models.ForeignKey(Candidato, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    adjunto = models.FileField(upload_to=UPLOAD_CVS)
    fecha_ingreso_cv = models.DateField(_("Date"), auto_now_add=True)

    def get_ultima_actualizacion(self):
        actual = datetime.now().date()
        return int(round((actual - self.fecha_ingreso_cv).days / 365,0))

    def get_cv_name(self):
        return 
       "CV_"+self.rut_candidato.nombre+"_"+self.rut_candidato.apellido+"_"+ str(self.fecha_ingreso_cv)
```

Settings.py:

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []



INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'INTRANET.apps.IntranetConfig',
    'localflavor',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'etalentNET.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['./templates',],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'etalentNET.wsgi.application'
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

#Cambiar a chile
TIME_ZONE = 'Chile/Continental'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

MEDIA_URL = '/INTRANET/uploads/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'INTRANET/uploads')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Por ahora, mientras no se configure envio email https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/email/
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'

# Redirect to home URL after login (Default redirects to /accounts/profile/)
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
```

Comment: can you post the model `documento` ? and also your root `urls.py` just to see if you have well configured your settings

Comment: @Lemayzeur just added;  documento => Curriculum in my model

Comment: your root urls.py as well

Comment: **ONLY IF DEBUG**: do you have this line in your urls.py : `urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have this line in your root `urls.py`, add it

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

> Note: This, WORKS ONLY IN DEVELOPMENT

Your `MEDIA_URL` should start with a `/`.
So instead of `MEDIA_URL = 'INTRANET/uploads/'`, add this:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/INTRANET/uploads/' 
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'INTRANET/uploads') # no Slash before  and after
```

In templates, you don't even need to add the path, Django will generate it:
instead of `../uploads/{{ documento.adjunto }}`, add `{{ documento.adjunto.url }}`

```
<embed src="{{ documento.adjunto.url }}"
       type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="600px" />
```

Comment: Just change all following what you say but it continue 
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/INTRANET/uploads/curriculums/CV_2017.pdf 404 (Not Found)

Comment: can you just `print(documento.adjunto.url )` in your views or in the html `<h1>{{ documento.adjunto.url  }}</h1>` and show me what you see in the console or the browser.

Comment: <p>Ubicacion CV: {{documento.adjunto.url}}</p>

Then:
Ubicacion CV: /INTRANET/uploads/curriculums/CV_2017.pdf

Comment: MEDIA_ROOT in your settings.py is not correct, updated my answer, check it

Comment: That Work! The error go away, but its still not showing anything

Answer (score 0):

### you can also use

```
doc = doc_models.objects.all()
<a href="{{doc.url}}">Pdf</a>
```